# POST nested JSON Body using asp mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, rest

I am trying to post a nested json body to an api and I tried few things but couldn't work it out. Another thing is the Json values are coming from different models. It is a bit complicated and I am struggling with it, any kind of help will be appreciated.

```
public Object getfreight()
    {
         var json = "{" +
"'from': {" +
    "'postcode': '3207'" +
"}," +
"'to': {" +
    "'postcode': '2001'" +
"}," +
"'items': [" +
    "{" +
        "'length': 5," +
        "'height': 5," +
        "'width': 5," +
        "'weight': 5," +
        "'item_reference' : 'abc xyz'," +
        "'features':{" +
            "'TRANSIT_COVER': {" +
                "'attributes': {" +
                    "'cover_amount':1000" +
                "}" +
            "}" +
        "}" +
    "}" +
"]" +
"}";

 string url = 
"https://digitalapi.auspost.com.au/postage/parcel/domestic/calculate.json?length=22&to_postcode=3083&from_postcode=3076&weight=2&height=40&width=50&service_code=AUS_PARCEL_REGULAR";


         //synchronous client.
        var client = new WebClient();
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("***", "***"); 

        client.Headers.Add("Content-Type: application/json");
        client.Headers.Add("Accept: application/json");
        client.Headers.Add("account-number: ***");
        var data = serializer.Serialize(json);
        var content = client.UploadString(url,json);

        var jsonContent = serializer.Deserialize<Object>(content);
        return jsonContent;
    }
```

Comment: what is this "nested json body" you speak of?

Comment: Do you have a sample Json?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the code, Please see the JSON data now.

Comment: You have this line `var data = serializer.Serialize(JsonData);` but you are not using the `data` variable anywhere

Comment: Yes because the JsonData is not valid yet, it is giving error, after fix that then I have to add it as body. If I am not wrong I can add the body using WebClient()!

Comment: I do not think this will compile.  "Yes because the JsonData is not valid yet, it is giving error" show that error don't keep us wondering.

Comment: Hi, I have fixed it with treating the var as string but now having problem in passing the credentials,                                                        
           client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("***", "***");                        Any suggestion what should I use??

Comment: It seems Your `Json` is not valid when validated  [online](https://jsonlint.com/), can you post pure Json without those `+`  and `"` or  try convert your object to `Json` using [this](http://csharp2json.azurewebsites.net/) site.

Answer (score 0):

Can't use jQuery to pass your json object to API ?

```
 function Search () {
       try {
                    var req = {
                        length:"5",
                        Higet: "10",
                        item_reference: "",  
                    }

                    $.ajax({
                        url: https://digitalapi.auspost.com.au/postage/parcel/domestic,
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: req,
                        dataType: "json",
                        async: true,
                        success: function (result) { 


                        },
                        error: function (e) {

                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (e) {

                }
            }
```